# Make Zend find my custom application exceptions

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, exception

I have a question similar to this thread : [throwing-exceptions-from-model-view-controller-in-a-zend-framework-application][1]

I have a standard MVC structure like this:

```
/application
/myapp
    /controllers
    /forms
    /models
    /exceptions
        Default.php (class Myapp_Exception_Default extends Zend_Exception)
```

And no matter what when I try to do:

```
throw new Myapp_Exception_Default();
```

I get :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Myapp_Exception_Default' not found
```

My question is how to make Zend find my custom Exceptions ? I didn't find any configuration options to declare it.

Comment: You can declare `Myapp_` namespace in application.ini !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like this:

```
boostrap.php
```

With this content:

```
...

protected function _initAutoload()
{
    // Add autoloader empty namespace
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoLoader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(true);//http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Trouble-using-Gdata-Calendar-td675383.html
    $autoLoader->registerNamespace('Gestionale_');
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
        array(
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace' => '',
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                'form' =>
                    array(
                        'path' => 'forms/',
                        'namespace' => 'Form_',
                    ),
                'model' =>
                    array(
                        'path' => 'models/',
                        'namespace' => 'Model_'
                    ),
            ),
    ));
    // Return it so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
    return $autoLoader;
}
```

...

```
\library\Gestionale\Exceptions\Exception.php
```

with this code

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom exception class that logs messages
 */
class Gestionale_Exceptions_Exception extends Exception
{
...
}
```

and then use

```
throw new Gestionale_Exceptions_Exception('Bla bla bla');
```

Comment: I knew this solution but I wanted to avoid as much as possible to put specific Exception of Myapp into my library folder because I reuse the library folder frequently in other applications so I wanted to keep it the more general possible.
Anyway I'm gonna go with this solution for now because it is a clean solution even if not the most logical if I referer to the purpose of the custom Exceptions.
If anyone knows better please share :)
Thanks for the quick and detailed answer

Comment: what if you add something like  'resourceTypes' => array(
                'error' =>
                    array(
                        'path' => 'exceptions/',
                        'namespace' => 'MyApp_',
                    ),
could work maybe

Comment: Noop it didn't work. Even by trying to declare it in my ini config file.